# Libgdx Spritebatch bug

Tags: java, graphics, libgdx, 2d

however, i have a weird issue, when drawing, it seems the outside 1px of an image is stretched to fit a rectangle, but the inside is only stetched to an extend, i was drawing to 48x48 tiles, but drew a 500x500 tile to show the issue. [ 500x500 draws fine ]
the worst part seems to be, it chooses when to stretch and not to stretch. and also what to strech. im sorry this is hard to explain but i have attached a image that i hope does a better job.
[image]it could just be misunderstanding how to use a draw with spritebatch
**edit: Tile is 48x48 not 64x64, ive just been working all day.**

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are not rendering "pixel perfect" which means your image does not line up with the pixel grid of your monitor. A quick fix might be to set a linear filter for your textures, since by default it uses nearest and thus a pixel on the screen will inherit the closest color it can get. A linear filter will interpolate colors and make that line "look" thinner.

```
texture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
```

If you are using texturepacker you can do this in one go by altering it's settings.

```
texturePackerSetting.filterMin = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear;
texturePackerSetting.filterMag = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear;
```

Or you could edit the atlas file itself by by changing the filter parameter to:

```
filter: Linear,Linear
```

This obviously costs more power since it needs to do more calculations for each pixel you drawn to the screen but I would not worry about this until your drawing is starting to get a bottleneck.

Another solutions is to draw pixel perfect which means you need to set your viewport to the size of the device `gdx.graphics.getWidth`, `gdx.graphics.getHeight`, in other words a `ScreenViewport` and draw your textures at exact sizes you want them. Of course this means a screen with more pixels sees more of your game world then a screen with less pixels and the more pixels a device has the smaller your textures will look. Another drawback of this is that you have to forget about any zooming or draw sprites for each level of zoom so they line up with the pixel grid of the device again.

Comment: Third option is to draw 1:1 to a FrameBuffer and than draw the FrameBuffer's texture to the screen with an upscaling shader (so you can reduce the blurriness that linear scaling would produce).

Comment: @Tenfour04 Interesting, do you mind adding that as an answer with a bit more details?

Comment: Thank you so much madmenyo. :)   

texture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);

didnt help me so much. 

neither did using a texutre atlas with linear.  

my viewport is keeping the ratio and thats helping a little but im trying framebuffer today. ill update if it helps or not. :)